# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to rank vehicles bought in the specified time range with more than 10000 prices, from the latest date to the oldest date and from the highest price to the lowest price. Sorry for my bad English!

```
SELECT alim_tarih, alim_fiyat, arac_no
FROM ALIS
WHERE alim_fiyat > 10000 
  AND alim_tarih BETWEEN '01/02/2010' AND '30/06/2010' 
ORDER BY alim_tarih ASC, alim_fiyat DESC
```

Comment: What is the data type of `alim_tarih`? Even if it is date [I recommend against `BETWEEN`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9316/sql-server-between-dates-issue/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard date formats:

```
WHERE alim_fiyat > 10000 AND
      alim_tarih BETWEEN '20100102' AND '20200630'
```

I actually prefer using dates with hyphens:

```
      alim_tarih BETWEEN '2010-01-02' AND '2020-06-30'
```

Under some circumstances, these *could* be interpreted as YYYY-DD-MM.